# Cakephp 2.5x password hashing. Security class or SimplePasswordHasher?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.5

I am looking for option where I can encrypt an application password which is unique to that app. Example, the same database won't work if the salt changes Security.salt of an app is usually unique.

[This link](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html) shows an example of `new SimplePasswordHasher(['hashType' => 'sha256'])->has($data)`

However, when I checking Api of Security class I saw [this function](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/source-class-Security.html#106) which is a static function and I can supply sha256 and default salt to true. I am not using blowfish.

`AuthComponent::password()` is deprecated so please do not suggest that.

Which is more `Cake` way of doing things?

Comment: The documentation usually doesn't lie. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#hashing-passwords is the truth.

Comment: I posted the answer. However, I can still supply `blowfish` and hash set to true. Shouldn't that be an issue?

Comment: Don't do it then :) Provide valid input. Or switch the PasswordHasher class.

Comment: Gah! That explains!! Thanks! Haha!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SimplePasswordHasher` calls `Security::hash`. Jeez!

Ref:
http://api.cakephp.org/2.5/source-class-SimplePasswordHasher.html#33-42

Answer (score 0):

In your auth models:

```
public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
    parent::beforeSave();
    if (!empty($this->data['Model']['password'])) {
        $this->data['Model']['password'] = Security::hash($this->data['Model']['password'], 'sha256', true);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I am sorry but how is this outdated? Instead of using $passwordHasher = new SimplePasswordHasher(array('hashType' => 'sha256'));
            $this->data['User']['password'] = $passwordHasher->hash(
                $this->data['User']['password'] I think calling a static method lowers the iteration count and thus - some performance improvements? Let me post on Github

Comment: See the [invalid issue](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/4043) you opened ;) And the answer there.